# Saving data that depends on a selected field

Tags: php

I want to save data depending on the option selected on the select menu, its option has a certain percentage attached to it, i tried using the code below but its only saving one value irregardless of which option is selected.

I have tried to use conditional-field by Steven Wanderski, but its only saving one value in all selections

my index.php

```
  <?php
    require_once('config.php');
    require_once('function.php');
    ?>



    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

          <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="js/conditional-field.min.js"></script>



        </head>
        <body>


    <div class="container mt-3">

        <form role="form" method="post" action="process.php">

           <?php $grant="20";
           $direct_cost="100";
           $discounts="100";
           $overhead_costs="70";
           ?>

            <p class="h4 mb-4">Supplier Spends</p>

            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                <div class="col">

                    <label for="prog_description">Name of the Programme:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                    <input type="text" id="prog_description" name="prog_description" class="form-control" placeholder="enter name of the programme embarked on" required>
                </div>

            </div>

            <label for="type_of_contrib">Type of Contribution:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inl`enter code here`ine; float: none;">*</span>
            <select name="type_of_contrib" id="TypeOfContribution" class="TypeOfContribution form-control mb-4"  required>
            <option value="">--select type of contribution--</option>
            <option value="Grant Contribution">Grant Contribution</option>
        <option value="Direct cost incurred">Direct cost incurred</option>
        <option value="discounts"> Discounts</option>
        <option value="Overheads costs">Overheads costs</option>
        <option value="Standard Loan">Standard Loan</option>
        <option value="Lower Interest Rate">Lower Interest Rate</option>
        <option value="Guarantees Provided">Guarantees Provided</option>
        <option value="Minority Investment">Minority Investment</option>
        <option value="Services at no Cost">Services at no Cost</option>
        <option value="Services at a Discount">Services at a Discount</option>
        <option value="Time of Employees">Time of Employees</option>
        <option value="Shorter payment periods">Shorter payment periods</option>
        <option value="Investment with lower Dividend">Investment with lower Dividend</option>
        </select>


        <div class="benefit form-row mb-4 ">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Grant Contribution">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor" class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="<?php echo $grant;?>"  readonly="readonly" required>

            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="benefit2 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Direct cost incurred">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor" class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="<?php echo $direct_cost;?>" readonly="readonly" required>
            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="benefit3 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Discounts">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor"class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="<?php echo $discounts;?>" readonly="readonly" required>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="benefit4 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Overheads costs">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor"class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="<?php echo $overhead_costs;?>" readonly="readonly"  required>
            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="benefit5 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Standard Loan">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor"class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="70" readonly="readonly"  required>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="benefit6 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Lower Interest Rate">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor"class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="50" readonly="readonly"  required>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="benefit7 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Guarantees Provided">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor" class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="3" readonly="readonly"   required>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="benefit8 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Minority Investment">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor"class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="70" readonly="readonly"  required>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="benefit9 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Services at no Cost">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor" class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="60" readonly="readonly"  required>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="benefit10 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Services at a Discount">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor" class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="60" readonly="readonly"  required>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="benefit11 form-row mb-4">
            <div class="col">

                <label for="Time of Employees">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor" class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="60" readonly="readonly"  required>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="benefit12 form-row mb-4" value="100";>
            <div class="col">

                <label for="shorter payment periods">Benefit Factor:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
                <input type="text" id="benefit_factor" name="benefit_factor" class="form-control" placeholder="benefit factor" value="15" readonly="readonly" required>
            </div>

        </div>




        <label for="budgeted_spend">Budgeted Spend:</label>
        <input type="number" id="budgeted_spend" name="budgeted_spend" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Budgeted Spend" required>


        <label for="actual_amount">Actual Amount Spent:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
        <input type="number" id="actual_amount" name="actual_amount" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Actual Amount Spent" required>

        <label for="current_status">Status of the programme:</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">*</span>
        <select name="current_status" id="current_status" class="status form-control mb-4"  required>
        <option disabled  selected>--select current status--</option>
        <option value="started">started</option>
        <option value="in_progress">in-progress</option>
        <option value="completed">completed</option>
        <option value="cancelled">cancelled</option>
        </select>

        <label for="anticipated_completion">Anticipated Completion Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="anticipated_completion" name="anticipated_completion" class="form-control mb-4" required>


        <button class="btn btn-info my-4 btn-block" type="submit">Save Data</button>




    </form>

<br>

<?php
            get_all_records();
            ?>


</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
new ConditionalField({
  control: '.TypeOfContribution',
  visibility: {
    'Grant Contribution': '.benefit',
    'Direct cost incurred': '.benefit2',
    'discounts': '.benefit3',
    'Overheads costs': '.benefit4',
    'Standard Loan': '.benefit5',
    'Lower Interest Rate': '.benefit6',
    'Guarantees Provided': '.benefit7',
    'Minority Investment': '.benefit8',
    'Services at no Cost': '.benefit9',
    'Services at a Discount': '.benefit10',
    'Time of Employees': '.benefit11',
    'Shorter payment periods': '.benefit12',

    }

   });
});

</script>

?>
```

Comment: Your form contains many input fields with the same id and name. id's _must_ be unique within the document (no two elements can share an id). Regarding names, multiple inputs can share the same name, but then you must use `benefit_factor[]` (with the [] at the end) to send all those inputs as an array. If not, only one (the first it founds) will be used/submitted. Also, forms that are hidden (display none) will still be a part of the form and submitted.

Comment: thanks  a lot, let me try that one, can you please at least help me with code sample

Comment: Code sample of what? All you need to do is to give each input a unique name and id.

Comment: ok thanks but i wanted to save all benefit_factor data in one field depending on which tupe_of_contrib is selected

Comment: @MagnusEriksson consider to convert your comment to an answer. This may help others with the same problem.